# How to assign a collection of 3 pieces of data

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have some dozens of tuples each containing 2 strings and 1 integer. Ex:`(str, str, int)`.
All these tuples are in a list (example below).
Each tuple is unique and each tuple's strings and integer are also unique.

Ex.:

```
[('a','aA', 53),
 ('b','bb', 21),
 ('c','cc', 234),
 ('d','de', 76),
..]
```

What I want is, to use this data structure like a dictionary and retrieve the entire tuple for any of **one of the 3 values** I pass.

> Ex.:
>
> For value `'a'` -> get the whole tuple of:`('a', 'aA', 53)`
>
> For value `'cc'` -> get the whole tuple of:`('c', 'cc', 234)`
>
> For value `'76'` - > get the whole tuple of:`('d', 'de', 76)`

So far I have done:
*Creating a simple function to iterate through the list of tuples, go through each tuple and its all 3 values to find a match and if there's a match return the tuple, if not return False.*

This sounds slow and seems like the very wrong way to do this task.

1. What would be the right way to achieve this?
2. Should I create 3 dictionaries and link them to each other?

Comment: how did you get `('d', 'de', 76)` for `'4'`?

Comment: Ashwini; you don't. It of course was a stupid typo.

Comment: How do you expect to deal with multiple matches?

Comment: Martijn, in this case it is certain that there would not be any multiple matches as all tuples and all values in tuples are %100 unique and will stay that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to create separate indexes using dictionaries to allow looking up elements by contents:

```
from collections import defaultdict

index_on_1 = defaultdict(list)
index_on_2 = defaultdict(list)
index_on_3 = defaultdict(list)

for i, (val1, val2, val3) in enumerate(yourstructure):
    index_on_1[val1].append(i)
    index_on_2[val2].append(i)
    index_on_3[val3].append(i)
```

Now you can look up indices on strings:

```
from itertools import chain

def lookup(entry):
    if isinstance(entry, str):
        entries = chain(index_on_1.get(entry, []), index_on_2.get(entry, []))
        return [yourstructure[i] for i in entries]
    else:
        return [yourstructure[i] for i in index_on_3.get(entry, [])]
```

Note that this always returns a list, as your entries could match multiple tuples. If the lookup is a string, we only use the first two indexes, otherwise only the 3rd.

Alternatively, the more general solution that doesn't care about entry type, would be to create a list of indexes, instead of 3 separate variables:

```
indexes = [defaultdict(list) for _ in range(3)]

for i, values in enumerate(yourstructure):
    for index, val in zip(indexes, values):
        index[val].append(i)
```

with the lookup becoming:

```
def lookup(entry):
    entries = chain(*[index.get(entry, []) for index in indexes])
    return [yourstructure[i] for i in entries]
```

You could bundle this all up in a class, where your indexes are kept up to date as you add or remove elements.

Comment: Martijn, thank you for your time and explanations. I learn a lot from you. I believe your first approach is the most sensible way in computer programming so I will create indexes. It makes more sense. Just to keep resource usage low, I should not scramble the code I guess. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The easy, unsophisticated method is:

```
>>> your_list
[('a', 'aA', 53), ('b', 'bb', 21), ('c', 'cc', 234), ('d', 'de', 76)]
>>> def get_tuple(list_of_tuples, elem):
...     for item in list_of_tuples:
...             if elem in item:
...                     return item
...     return False
... 
>>> get_tuple(your_list, 'a')
('a', 'aA', 53)
>>> get_tuple(your_list, 'cc')
('c', 'cc', 234)
```

Though, you didn't specify, what should happen if one element is in more than in one tuple.
What should be return for 'a' in list of

```
[('a','aA', 53),
('b','bb', 21),
('a','ca', 234),
..]
```

Answer (score 1):

To keep a `O(1)` look up you can create a dictionary like this from those tuples:

```
In [20]: lis=[('a','aA', 53),
   ....:  ('b','bb', 21),
   ....:  ('c','cc', 234),
   ....:  ('d','de', 76)]

In [22]: dic=dict((y,x) for x in lis for y in x)

In [23]: dic

Out[23]: 
{21: ('b', 'bb', 21),
 53: ('a', 'aA', 53),
 76: ('d', 'de', 76),
 234: ('c', 'cc', 234),
 'a': ('a', 'aA', 53),
 'aA': ('a', 'aA', 53),
 'b': ('b', 'bb', 21),
 'bb': ('b', 'bb', 21),
 'c': ('c', 'cc', 234),
 'cc': ('c', 'cc', 234),
 'd': ('d', 'de', 76),
 'de': ('d', 'de', 76)}
```

now searching any item becomes easy:

```
In [24]: dic.get('a','not found')
Out[24]: ('a', 'aA', 53)

In [25]: dic.get('aA','not found')
Out[25]: ('a', 'aA', 53)

In [26]: dic.get('21','not found')
Out[26]: 'not found'

In [27]: dic.get(21,'not found')
Out[27]: ('b', 'bb', 21)
```